# Can't find installed virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed `Virtualbox` but I am total newbie of this directory hierarchy. Now I can't find it. The downloaded file is:
`virtualbox-5.2_5.2.22-126460_Ubuntu_bionic_amd64.deb`. After executed it by double click it installed `Virtualbox`. Now where should I search for it? Whit `find -name "virtualbox*"` I can find it in more than few folders:

```
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.templates
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.postrm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.prerm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.preinst
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.postinst
./var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-5.2.md5sums
./var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-updates-multiverse/64x64/virtualbox-qt_virtualbox.png
./var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-multiverse/64x64/virtualbox-qt_virtualbox.png
./usr/bin/virtualbox
./usr/lib/virtualbox
./usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop
./usr/share/pixmaps/virtualbox.png
./usr/share/lintian/overrides/virtualbox-5.2
./usr/share/mime/packages/virtualbox-5.2.xml
```

After ton of post and article I am totally discouraged about this `Linux` installations... Where should I search for the `.exe` file. ( I know it is not an `.exe` extension in Linux )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to start VirtualBox:  press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (also called the Windows key) and type "virtualbox" - the icon for launching will appear.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! But where should I find it the hierarchy ? Us I know it should be in `opt/` but it is not there.

Comment: You could try `locate virtualbox` or `which virtualbox`

Comment: You _may_ find it using `locate` _eventually_. :)